# In assembly language how to divides the screen into two equal horizontal colors, upper half is black and lower is magenta

Tags: monetdb-assembly-language

I have to make program in assembly language in which screen divides the screen into two equal horizontal colors using BIOS services. The colors of the upper and lower halves should be black and magenta respectively.